# Use jQuery method as callback parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this little jQuery plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
(function($){
    $.fn.foo = function(options){
        var options = $.extend({
            text: "Foo!",
            }, options
        );

        this.prepend(
            $("<span></span>").text(options.text)
        ).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);


$(function(){
    $("div").foo().foo({text: "Bar!"}).css({border: "1px solid red"});
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to improve it so you are able to control where the text gets inserted by means of providing a callback function:

```
$(function(){
    var optionsFoo = {
        text: "Foo!",
        insertionCallback: $.append
    }
    var optionsBar = {
        text: "Bar!",
        insertionCallback: $.prepend
    }
    $("div").foo(optionsFoo).foo(optionsBar).css({border: "1px solid red"});
});
```

(Please remember this is just sample code. I want to learn a technique rather than fix an issue.)

Can I pass a jQuery method as an argument and use it inside the plugin in the middle of a chain? If so, what's the syntax? If not, what's the recommended alternative?

## Update: myprogress so far

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
(function($){
    $.fn.foo = function(options){
        var options = $.extend({
            text: "Foo!",
            insertionCallback: $.append
            }, options
        );

        options.insertionCallback.call(this, // options.insertionCallback is undefined
            $("<span></span>").text(options.text)
        ).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);


$(function(){
    var optionsFoo = {
        text: "Foo!",
        insertionCallback: $.append
    }
    var optionsBar = {
        text: "Bar!",
        insertionCallback: $.prepend
    }
    $("div").foo(optionsFoo).foo(optionsBar).css({border: "1px solid red"});
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, JavaScript is really dynamic:

```
    this.prepend(
        $("<span></span>").text(options.text)
    ).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});
```

You can replace the native call to `this.prepend()` with the jQuery function you pass in the options object as a parameter.

Since most jQuery methods behave on a current set of elements (the `this` object in your plugin) you need to use `apply` or `call` to make it work. This way you can call the `options.insertionCallback` function with the current `this` object as its context.

Something like:

```
    options.insertionCallback.call(this, // pass the current context to the jQuery function
        $("<span></span>").text(options.text)
    ).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});
```

**Edit**

However you can't access jQuery methods directly from the `$` namespace, you need a constructed jQuery object to access its methods, or simply use `$.fn.functionName` as Nick Craver pointed out.

```
alert($.prepend); // won't alert the function

alert($.fn.prepend); // will alert the function
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your example a little more? I cannot grasp the exact syntax. I get *options.insertionCallback is undefined* no matter what I do.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: That's because $.prepend (or $.append) is undefined. I elaborated a bit more in the answer.

Comment: You can access the methods directly, `$.fn.prepend` ;)

Comment: That did the trick in my sample code: use `$.fn.prepend` to set and `options.insertionCallback.call(this,...)` to call. I understand the callback execution must normally start the method chain if previous methods change the element selection but it's a reasonable drawback. Nick's string trick is also neat.

Answer (score 1):

extend it like so:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.foo = function(options){
        var options = $.extend({
            text: "Foo!",
            cb: null
            }, options
        );

        if($.isFunction(options.cb)){
           // optimal also pass parameters for that callback
           options.cb.apply(this, []);
        }

        this.prepend(
            $("<span></span>").text(options.text)
        ).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I don't really understand what you mean with

> Can I pass a jQuery method as an argument and use it inside the plugin in the middle of a chain?

Why would you want to pass a `jQuery method` ? it's already in there so you can just call it on any `jQuery object`.

Comment: What I mean is being able to do this inside the plugin: `this.insertionCallback($("<span></span>").text(options.text)
).css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this string based to keep it simple, like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.foo = function(options){
    var options = $.extend({
        text: "Foo!",
        insertionCallback: "append"
        }, options
    );
    return this[options.insertionCallback]($("<span></span>").text(options.text))
               .css({color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"});
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then your call looks like this:

```
$(function(){
  var optionsFoo = {
    text: "Foo!",
    insertionCallback: "append"
  }
  var optionsBar = {
    text: "Bar!",
    insertionCallback: "prepend"
  }
  $("div").foo(optionsFoo).foo(optionsBar).css({border: "1px solid red"});
});​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/2NcKM/2/), this would allow you to use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), giving you a few options to set the content.  In this case we're just taking advantage of JavaScript being a dynamic language, where `this.prepend(something)` is equal to `this["prepend"](something)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but the recommended style is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //this
  jQuery(function($) {
    //... stuff using the jQuery lib, using the $
  });

  //not this
  $(function() {
    //...
  });

  //or this
  (function($) {
    //...
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: The last one is the "Custom Alias in plugin code" described at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Custom_Alias but I take note of the alias in page code, which I was not aware of.

Comment: Right, this is for page code. Plugin code should always use the last style example instead of the first.